# Python BZ2 Compressor - compress() not returning anything

Tags: python, stream, buffer, compression, bzip2

I am trying to compress a data stream using pythons bz2compressor class.

The documentation says `bz2compressor.compress()` should return chunks of compressed data "whenever possible" but I don't get anything

I get ALL my compressed data when I `flush()` (I have tried with files 2GB+) still nothing.

Is there a way I can set any internal buffer limit to when it should return me data.

Thanks!

Comment: "I get ALL my compressed data when I flush() (I have tried with files 2GB+) still nothing."?  What does this mean?  Do you get the data with flush?  If so, then what's your question?  Are you wondering why it doesn't seem to actually return chunks?

Comment: Hi, yes I want small chunks from bz2compressor.compress() (documentation says this function is supposed to return chucks)

Comment: It's not *required* to return chunks.  The implementation, it appears, doesn't need to.  It appears you have way, way too much memory in your computer.

Comment: I know its not _required_ hence the question: Is there a way I can force it to return chunks - maybe flush internal buffer.. something like that

Answer (score 3):

> I get ALL my compressed data when I flush() (I have tried with files 2GB+) still nothing.

There's a trick to working with compressors.

I'll bet that your 2GB+ file was not very random.  Random data doesn't compress well.  Orderly data compresses to a very small size.

For example

```
>>> import bz2
>>> c=bz2.BZ2Compressor()
>>> import string
>>> data = string.printable*1024
>>> len(data)
102400
>>> c.compress(data)
''
>>> result= c.flush()
>>> len(result)
361
```

The data being supplied had a pattern, which made it compress well.

You need random data.

```
>>> import random
>>> c=bz2.BZ2Compressor()
>>> size= 0
>>> result= ''
>>> while result == '':
...     data = ''.join( random.choice(string.printable) for i in xrange(1024*8) )
...     size += len(data)
...     result= c.compress(data)... 
>>> len(result)
754809
>>> size
901120
```

I get chunks when I use really random data.